# How do I use RowFilter to to find the length of the longest string in a column?

Tags: c#, datatable, rowfilter

This table only exists in memory, so can't do a quick SQL query.

I need to find the longest string in a column of a datatable.

Due to the size of the tables processed I can not just do a raw row-by-row size check, but have to use RowFilter.

I've tried these:

```
 dv.RowFilter = "[" + colName + "] = MAX([" + colName + "])"//incorrect results
```

and

```
dv.RowFilter = "[" + colName + "] = MAX(LEN([" + colName + "]))" // Gives error "Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."
```

and

```
dv.RowFilter = "MAX(LEN([" + colName + "]))" // Gives error "Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

OK, So I got it working with the following:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "[fieldsize_" + colName + "] = MAX([fieldsize_" + colName + "])"; //add column for size
dataTableSize = dataView.ToTable();

string strMaxValue = dataTableSize.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
int colSize =  strMaxValue.Length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try on these lines

```
string maxstring = (string)dt.Compute("MAX(C1)","ISNULL(C1,'') <> ''");
```

here C1 is your concerned columnname and you get the max string value in the column and you could easily find the length from it.

*This works for non-text columns.*

**For text columns**, you can go about adding an additional column which would be evaluated as `LEN(C1)` (using `Expression` property of the new columm and then you can filter based on `MAX`

Comment: This incorrect: you have duplicated the results I get with my first try as shown above. It merely returns the alphabeticaly last entry

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, the `Compute` should return the longest string

Comment: Your comment "Else you can also go about adding an additional column " is what led me to the solution, hence the green light for you.

Comment: It wont work. If you have two strings "Abc" and "Xy", it will give "Xy" instead of "Abc". as Max will return Xy

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Did you read the else part, which is based on length the last para to be exact.

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yes. Edit your answer and will remove down vote. Not allowing to remove down vote.